# Why can't I read Strings from a file?

Tags: java, string, file-io, java.util.scanner

The code is supposed to read an array of strings from a file then print it out. I'm not sure what is wrong with the code.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class program2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        //PriorityQueue<String> q = new PriorityQueue<String>();
        //file that contains strings
        File file = new File("infix.txt");
        Scanner scnf = new Scanner(file);
        // array count
        int arycnt = 0; 
        // gets the count of the array in the file
        while(scnf.hasNextLine()){
            arycnt++;
            scnf.next();
        }
        // creates array
        String[] letter = new String[arycnt];
        //reads in array from  file
        Scanner scnf2 = new Scanner(file);
        for(int i = 0; i<arycnt ;i++){
            letter[i] = scnf2.next();
        }
        // suppose to print all of the array
        for (int i = 0;i < letter.length;i++){
            System.out.println(letter[i]);
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: You never close the two `Scanner` objects, so you're leaking resources. I would also suggest using an `ArrayList<String>` instead of the `String[]`, so you don't have to read the file twice.

Answer (score 2):

You are mixing up between `nextLine` and `next`. Replace your `hasNextLine()` with `hasNext()` and you should be OK.

Comment: Or replace `next()` with `nextLine()`, depending on whether the "strings" in the file are each on their own lines, or are "tokens" separated by spaces.